# Listing of typical correlations across spectrum of topics and disciplines to assist with teaching meaning of correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis, teaching

#### Context

When I teach students about the correlation coefficient, I like to give students a sense of how correlations map on to common associations that might be encountered in daily life and across various topics and disciplines.

Some years back I read a psychology journal article  (it might have been American Psychologist) that presented a table of meta analytic correlations across a wide range of topics and disciplines (e.g., 40 or 50 correlations from medical, psychological, economic, and other domains). The table aimed to highlight what are typical correlations in a given domain in order to provide context for the interpretation of a correlation coefficient. However, I can't remember the reference for the particular journal article.

#### Question

- Does anyone know where a general listing of the magnitude of typical correlations across a wide range of disciplines and topics could be obtained?

Comment: I remember Cohen doing something like this (though focusing more on R2) in his book Statistical Power Analysis for the Social and Behavioural Sciences, so I would suspect that he may have written the article you are referring to.

Comment: I think you are remembering this article: Meyer et al. (2001). Psychological testing and psychological assessment: A review of evidence and issues. American Psychologist, 56(2), 128-165 [(PubMed link)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11279806). Something similar for standardized mean differences can be found here: Lipsey, M. W., & Wilson, D. B. (1993). The efficacy of psychological, educational, and behavioral treatment. American Psychologist, 48(12), 1181-1209 [(PubMed link)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8297057).

Comment: @Wolfgang excellent. Thanks so much. The Meyer article is exactly what I was thinking of. Would you be able to put your comment as an answer so that I can close off on the question?

Comment: @Jeromy Gladly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are remembering this article: Meyer et al. (2001). Psychological testing and psychological assessment: A review of evidence and issues. American Psychologist, 56(2), 128-165 [(PubMed link)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11279806).

Something similar for standardized mean differences can be found here: Lipsey, M. W., & Wilson, D. B. (1993). The efficacy of psychological, educational, and behavioral treatment. American Psychologist, 48(12), 1181-1209 [(PubMed link)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8297057).